# How to write VBA macro to add recuring tasks to PBI's in Project attached to Azure DevOps

Tags: vba, azure, azure-devops, ms-project

I am working on an Agile Scrum based project using Azure DevOps. I want an MS Project macro that will allow me to add a set of tasks to PBI's that are returned by a particular query.

I can connect to Azure DevOps using the 'Team' plugin for Office, so I can get the query results in Microsoft Project.

This will be used after every Sprint Planning to automate adding tasks to user stories in bulk rather than having to do it by hand.

So if the query returns a PBI such as:

```
Work Item ID | Title        | Work Item Type | 

  1234       | PBI Name1    | Product Backlog Item |
  1235       | PBI Name2    | Product Backlog Item |
```

After the macro is run, I'd have

```
Work Item ID | Title        | Work Item Type | 

  1234       | PBI Name1    | Product Backlog Item |
             |     Task 1   | Task                 |
             |     Task 2   | Task                 |
  1235       | PBI Name2    | Product Backlog Item |
             |     Task 1   | Task                 |
             |     Task 2   | Task                 |
```

Is this possible to do in VBA?

Comment: If your question is "can I add tasks using VBA?" the answer is yes. Here's an example: [stackoverflow.com/questions/51136478/how-do-i-automatically-create-summary-and-subtasks-in-microsoft-project-using-vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136478/how-do-i-automatically-create-summary-and-subtasks-in-microsoft-project-using-vb). As currently posted, your question will likely get closed as too broad/vague. Try to be more specific, show what you have done so far, and explain the specific areas of difficulty.

Comment: This is specifically in relationship to a connection to Azure DevOps . . . does that change anything?

Comment: If you can query the data in vba and receive the results in a usable format, the source should not matter.

Comment: Do you want to write these tasks to DevOps or a Project document?